# why data is updating during validation

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and JPA.  I'm validating a form.  However, during validation data is getting updated to data base.  I'm not understanding why this is happening.  Can anybody tell me why the data is updating during validation?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public String save(HttpServletRequest request,
        @ModelAttribute("modelObject") Ticket entity,
        BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model) {
    String type = request.getParameter("type");

    request.getSession().setAttribute("subcontractor", entity.getSubcontractor());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("truck", entity.getVehicle());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("trailer", entity.getTrailer());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("terminal", entity.getTerminal());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("enteredBy", entity.getCreatedBy());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("batchDate", entity.getBillBatch());

    // Validate for Duplicate OriginTicket#
    if (type.equals("complete")) {  
        // validate entity
        try {
            getValidator().validate(entity, bindingResult);
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.warn("Error in validation :" + e);
        }
        if (entity.getDriver() == null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("driver", "error.select.option",
                    null, null);
        }
        if (entity.getVehicle() == null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("vehicle", "error.select.option",
                    null, null);
        }
        if (entity.getOrigin() == null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("origin", "error.select.option",
                    null, null);
        }
        if (entity.getDestination() == null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("destination", "error.select.option",
                    null, null);
        }
        if (entity.getTrailer() == null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("trailer", "error.select.option",
                    null, null);
        }
        if (entity.getCreatedBy() == null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("createdBy", "error.select.option",
                    null, null);
        }
        if (entity.getUnloadDate()!=null && entity.getLoadDate()!=null) {
            if (entity.getUnloadDate().before(entity.getLoadDate())) {
                bindingResult.rejectValue("unloadDate", "error.textbox.unloadDate",
                        null, null);
            }
        }
        if(reportService.checkDuplicate(entity,"O")){
            bindingResult.rejectValue("originTicket", "error.duplicate.entry",  null, null);        
        }
        if(reportService.checkDuplicate(entity,"D")){
            bindingResult.rejectValue("destinationTicket", "error.duplicate.entry", null, null);        
        }
        /*if (getUser(request).getBillBatchDate()!=null) {
            entity.setBillBatch(getUser(request).getBillBatchDate());
        }*/
        entity.setStatus(1);
        if(entity.getTicketStatus()!=2){
            System.out.println("\nentity.getTicketStatus()!=2\n");
        entity.setTicketStatus(1);
        }

        // return to form if we had errors
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            setupCreate(model, request);
            return urlContext + "/form";
        }
        beforeSave(request, entity, model);
        User user=genericDAO.getById(User.class,entity.getCreatedBy());
        entity.setEnteredBy(user.getName());
        // merge into datasource
        genericDAO.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        cleanUp(request);
        // return to list
        setupCreate(model, request);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("msg",
                "Ticket added successfully");
        return "redirect:create.do";
    } else {
        if(reportService.checkDuplicate(entity,"O")){
            bindingResult.rejectValue("originTicket", "error.duplicate.entry",  null, null);        
        }
        else if(reportService.checkDuplicate(entity,"D")){
            bindingResult.rejectValue("destinationTicket", "error.duplicate.entry", null, null);        
        }
        // return to form if we had errors
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            setupCreate(model, request);
            return urlContext + "/form";
        }
        //entity.setBillBatch(getUser(request).getBillBatchDate());

        //entity.setTicketStatus(0);
        entity.setStatus(3);
        if(entity.getTicketStatus()!=2){
            System.out.println("\nNEXT entity.getTicketStatus()!=2\n");
        entity.setTicketStatus(0);
        }
        beforeSave(request, entity, model);
        User user=genericDAO.getById(User.class,entity.getCreatedBy());
        entity.setEnteredBy(user.getName());

        genericDAO.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        return "redirect:create.do";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line

```
genericDAO.saveOrUpdate(entity);
```

be responsible for it?

Comment: before save or update i am validating the form .. but if field is empty validation working but data gets updated to database base.. with   null value..

Comment: data getting update even while validation because i am checking for duplicate entry which method in service class , in service class transaction is present so record is updating first and returning to controller class